# Blu-Ray to NAS via USB

Tags: networking, usb, blu-ray

I have a Samsung Blu-Ray player.  I like using a USB thumb drive to play slide shows, music, and videos on the home entertainment system.  However, regularly copying files to the thumb drive is annoying.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to connect a Blu-ray player to the home network?  I'm thinking specifically of using a USB wireless network adapter.  Are there any configurable/hackable network adapters that will masquerade as thumb drive (at least as far as my Blu-ray player is concerned)?  Are there any devices that would interface between the network adapter and the player that would do a similar thing?

Am I over-thinking this?  Are there other ways of gaining access to the network from the Blu-Ray player?

(I have a BD-P1600, If that helps, but a general solution for any device that works with USB storage device would be preferred.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any "general" solutions, but I would start off with solutions your player allows you to do.  The BD-P1600 allows for network access [already](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/2676359/samsung_bdp1600_bluray_disc_player.html?cat=15), so should be able to use that.  Try putting your files onto a windows share.  To do this, on your computer, right click the folder you want to share, go to properties, then go to sharing, and set it up. Also make sure your firewall is setup to allow this (as a last resort you can turn off the firewall, but this is not recommended).  You'll need a router to network the two devices, but hopefully you already have one of those.

Now that your folder is shared, you should hopefully be able to access it from your device.  Refer to the instruction manual it came with for more details.  I don't know much about this particular device (though I did verify the BD-P1600 has network support), but have used similar devices, and they can all do stuff like this.